# 301 redirect with ampersand in link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to set up redirect 301 in .htaccess file but old link contain & signs. So, it is not works
My old link: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=62&Itemid=75
so, I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&(.*)$
RewriteRule .+ / [R=301,L]
```

Can you help me with that?
Also I have this old link: /index.php?parametr1=services&parametr2=Recovery_Services&parametr3=Orthopedic_in_home_care

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a question mark at the end of the Rewrite destination

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&(.*)$
RewriteRule .+ /? [R=301,L]
```

? is important here to discard the old query string from the new url otherwise you will end up at **/?oldquerystring**